# update field when others fields are motifed

Tags: java, design-patterns

> I have a class `Installment` and a method `executeTransaction`. The field `totalBalance` represents the difference between total due and total paid. Inside method `executeTransaction` the installment object is modified using setters. And after every setter the updateTotalBalance is called.

```
public class Installment {
    private BigDecimal principalDue;
    private BigDecimal principalPaid;
    private BigDecimal interestDue;
    private BigDecimal interestPaid;
    private BigDecimal feeDue;
    private BigDecimal feePaid;
    private BigDecimal penaltyDue;
    private BigDecimal penaltyPaid;
    private BigDecimal totalBalance;

    public void updateTotalBalance() {
         this.totalBalance = this.principalDue.subtract(this.penaltyPaid)
            .add(this.interestDue).subtract(this.interestPaid)
            .add(this.feeDue).subtract(this.feePaid)
            .add(this.penaltyDue).subtract(this.penaltyPaid);
    }

    //seters
    //getters
}
```

Transaction method:

```
public void executeTransaction(Installment installment){
    //code
    installment.setPrincipalPaid(bigDecimalValue);
    installment.updateTotalBalance();
    //code
    installment.setPenaltyDue(bigDecimalValue);
    installment.updateTotalBalance();
}
```

I was thinking about putting the `updateTotalBalance` inside the setters, but for me both of these approaches seem contradictory with the best design principles.

Q: I want to know if there are better solutions to update a field in a class when others fields are modified.

Comment: May be the [_Observer_ design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) would be a more generic and flexible solution for that problem.

Comment: If it's not clear, the problem with this post is that it doesn't actually update the total balance when other fields are modified.  It updates when execute transaction is run.  So it does not actually accomplish the task that you say you're attempting.  You've also elided out all the context, so we can't suggest changes outside the code that you've posted.  This is required on Stack Overflow but is a close reason here.  Code here should be specific, not general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to drop the `totalBalance` field and simply have `getTotalBalance` calculate the value:

```
public BigDecimal getTotalBalance() {
    return this.principalDue.subtract(this.penaltyPaid)
        .add(this.interestDue).subtract(this.interestPaid)
        .add(this.feeDue).subtract(this.feePaid)
        .add(this.penaltyDue).subtract(this.penaltyPaid);
}
```

There is no real reason to store the total inside the object, unless you know it has to called multiple times (and with that I mean a very large number of times, not 3 or 4 times) without being able to be cached.

Generally with data classes it's always prudent to look into the possibility of having it be immutable (= no setters), then you only need calculate the total once in the constructor. I can't say for sure without more context, but this actually looks like a prime example where immutability could make sense.

Again with out more context its difficult to say, but IMO the class seems to contain too much information/data. It may make sense to break in down into smaller classes.